# set @var = exec stored_procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, exec

Is it possible to assign at variable a value returned from exec stored procedure?

Something like

```
DECLARE @count int
SET @count = Execute dbo.usp_GetCount @Id=123
```

Comment: Yopur question asks about `exec @sql` but the example you give calls a stored proc. What do you need?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec` to assign to scalar output parameters

```
DECLARE @out int

EXEC sp_executesql N'select @out_param=10',
                   N'@out_param int OUTPUT',
                     @out_param=@out OUTPUT

SELECT @out
```

For `exec` I'm only aware of how to do it using a table variable

```
declare @out table
(
out int
)

insert into @out
exec('select 10')

select * 
from @out
```

For stored procedures you would also use an `output` parameter or a return code. The latter can return a single integer only and generally preferred for returning error codes rather than data. Both techniques are demonstrated below.

```
create proc #foo 
@out int output
as
set @out = 100
return 99

go

declare @out int, @return int

exec @return = #foo @out output

select @return as [@return], @out as [@out]

drop proc #foo
```

Comment: thank you. I want to do something like this in my SP ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://abc.com') SET @out = ( SELECT XmlResult.value('count(//subjects/subject)', 'int') FROM @XmlTable ) But I get syntax error. This is driving me crazy

Comment: Use `SELECT @out =  XmlResult.value` to assign it to a scalar variable.

Comment: Thank you. I see the message (1 Rows(s) affected) but not the results with SELECt @out = xmlResult.Value... How can I see the results?

Comment: You would just do `SELECt @out` if you wanted to return it as a scalar or call the stored procedure as illustrated above to get it from an output parameter

Answer (score 27):

If you use RETURN in the proc

```
DECLARE @count int
EXECUTE @count = dbo.usp_GetCount @Id=123
```

OUTPUT parameter

```
DECLARE @count int
EXECUTE dbo.usp_GetCount @Id=123, @count OUTPUT
```

Redirect the results to temp table/table variable

```
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @cache TABLE (CountCol int NOT NULL)
INSERT @cache EXECUTE dbo.usp_GetCount @Id=123
SELECT @count = CountCol FROM @cache
```

You can't assign a recordset from the stored proc directly to a scalar variable

Answer (score 10):

As usual many ways to do this but the easiest is:

```
DECLARE @count int

Execute @count =  dbo.usp_GetCount @Id=123
```

Comment: Yes this will work but if you do not want to ourput the count value and just use it. This will not work.