# Returning a value from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a main procedure, and in this SP it does the following piece of code:

```
EXEC @PropertyID = [import].[spInsertIntoTblMemberProperties]
blah blah blah
```

And then in my spInsertIntoTblMemberProperties the following two lines of code:

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as 'MemberPropertyID'; (if it is a new property)
select MemberPropertyID as 'MemberPropertyID'; (if it is an existing property)
from blah blah blah
```

However, this doesn't make @PropertyID equal the 'MemberPropertID' and I was wondering how I would do so.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Why do you have two "select"?

Comment: Because one is for when a new property has been created and one is for when a property is updated. only one is touched in an execution

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I was tired when I read your message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need RETURN to do it yourway
This is not ideal though: this should be reserved for status.

I'd use an OUTPUT parameter

```
CREATE PROC ... 
    @PropertyID int OUTPUT
AS
...

select @PropertyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() as 'MemberPropertyID'; (if it is a new property)
...
select @PropertyID = MemberPropertyID as 'MemberPropertyID'; (if it is an existing property)
from blah blah blah
...
GO

EXEC [import].[spInsertIntoTblMemberProperties] @PropertyID OUTPUT
```

Example of differences in technique: [set @var = exec stored_procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439005/set-var-exec-storedprocedure/5441380#5441380)