# How create INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER PartnersTrigger on Partners
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON


Declare @Key nvarchar(10);

EXEC @Key = sp_GeneratePassword 5;

UPDATE Partners SET KeyInvitation  = @Key WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM inserted);
INSERT INTO Partners(Email,KeyInvitation)
   SELECT Email, KeyInvitation
FROM inserted
END
GO
```

But I need set to `KeyInvitation` variable `@Key`.
And set `sp_GeneratePassword 5` (procedure) in `@Key`.

How to do this?

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GeneratePassword
 (
     @Length int
 )

 AS

 DECLARE @RandomID varchar(32)
 DECLARE @counter smallint
 DECLARE @RandomNumber float
 DECLARE @RandomNumberInt tinyint
 DECLARE @CurrentCharacter varchar(1)
 DECLARE @ValidCharacters varchar(255)
 SET @ValidCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
 DECLARE @ValidCharactersLength int
 SET @ValidCharactersLength = len(@ValidCharacters)
 SET @CurrentCharacter = ''
 SET @RandomNumber = 0
 SET @RandomNumberInt = 0
 SET @RandomID = ''

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 SET @counter = 1

 WHILE @counter < (@Length + 1)

 BEGIN

         SET @RandomNumber = Rand()
         SET @RandomNumberInt = Convert(tinyint, ((@ValidCharactersLength - 1) * @RandomNumber + 1))

         SELECT @CurrentCharacter = SUBSTRING(@ValidCharacters, @RandomNumberInt, 1)

         SET @counter = @counter + 1

         SET @RandomID = @RandomID + @CurrentCharacter

 END

 SELECT @RandomID  AS 'Password'



GO
```

this not work:

```
Declare @Key nvar char(10);  -- can't post when I use "nvarchar" here
EXEC @Key = sp_GeneratePassword 5;
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'char'. Must declare the scalar variable "@Key".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Key". Must declare the scalar
>   variable "@Key".

Comment: There is mistake `Declare @Key nvar char(10);` should be `Declare @Key nvarchar(10);` (without space) but it will not work anyway. Check my answer, but please bear in mind that it sets same password for all records when they are inserted at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger looks OK apart from the info noted by Michal Powaga and this bit:

```
Declare @Key nvarchar(10);  -- can't post when I use "nvarchar" here
EXEC @Key = sp_GeneratePassword 5;
```

Unless `sp_GeneratePassword` has a `RETURN` with a specific value it will usually give 0 because this kind of call assigns the value from the `RETURN` to `@Key`. However, this can only be used for `int` values and `@Key` is nvarchar.

I'd use an output parameter like in this answer from yesterday: [Returning a value from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063273/returning-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure/8063390#8063390)

Note; you are assigning all rows in the INSERT the same password (don't assume triggers operate on single rows). I'd consider a DEFAULT constraint on the `KeyInvitation` column that calls a UDF. This avoids a trigger and will give different values (I assume)

Comment: @Deniska d: my comment says I couldn't post the work nvarchar above using my browser at work. Don't blindly copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you insert `@Key` the way described below:

**Edit**: changed after @gbn answer

Firstly, SP should look like this one bellow (it's all about `output` value):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GeneratePassword 
    @param_in INT, @key_out NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- here is your password generation
    SET @key_out = 'your result'
END
GO
```

**Update**: changed after @Deniskad explanation

Your SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GeneratePassword @Length int, @RandomID varchar(32) OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @counter smallint,
        @RandomNumber float,
        @RandomNumberInt tinyint,
        @CurrentCharacter varchar(1),
        @ValidCharacters varchar(255),
        @ValidCharactersLength int

    SET @ValidCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

    SELECT @ValidCharactersLength = len(@ValidCharacters),
        @CurrentCharacter = '',
        @RandomNumber = 0,
        @RandomNumberInt = 0,
        @RandomID = ''

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @counter = 1

    WHILE @counter < (@Length + 1)

    BEGIN
        SET @RandomNumber = Rand()
        SET @RandomNumberInt = Convert(tinyint, ((@ValidCharactersLength - 1) * @RandomNumber + 1))

        SELECT @CurrentCharacter = SUBSTRING(@ValidCharacters, @RandomNumberInt, 1)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1

        SET @RandomID = @RandomID + @CurrentCharacter
    END
GO
```

..then trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PartnersTrigger on Partners
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Declare @Key nvarchar(10);

    EXEC sp_GeneratePassword 5, @Key OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO Partners(Email,KeyInvitation)
    SELECT Email, @Key
    FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Comment: This shouldwork but would give everyone the same password if a batch of records were inserted.

Comment: It's true, but @Deniskad probably had not intention to use it to insert multiple records at once. `Declare @Key nvarchar(10); EXEC @Key = sp_GeneratePassword 5;` and than `@Key` used for "all" records indicates that.