# How to loop through stored procedure recordset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have this select statement

```
declare @t table (Percentage float)
DECLARE @acc INT 
SET @acc = 1
DECLARE @max INT 
select @max = max(HireID) from NewHire
WHILE (@acc <= @max)
    BEGIN
        IF (@acc in (select HireID from NewHire))
            BEGIN try
                insert into @t  
                select
                    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc AND (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
                    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc) as FLOAT)
            END try
            begin catch
                insert into @t 
                select 0.0
            end catch
        set @acc = @acc + 1
    END
select * from @t
```

In this code, I am looping through all the NewHire records by its id, from 1 to the highest one. I realized this is not what I want to do anymore. Now basically I have this stored procedure called `sp_selectNewHire2SQL` which gets the NewHire table in a specific way. I want to call it, and aquire its returning recordset, and then loop through that from top to bottom.

Note: That doing a loop from id 1 to highest wont work anymore, because the order of the id's could be mixed up.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: No, how does that work?

Comment: You don't want to loop, you need to stop thinking it terms of looping, that is not the way you handle database code. You need to think in terms of sets of data. Looping is a last resort, never a first one as it is slow and inefficient.

Comment: Do not under any circumstances use a cursor!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, cursor may be last option you can think of! but If you want to loop through each of your record set then cursor might be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    NH.HireID,
    ISNULL(1E0 *
          COUNT(CASE WHEN HireResponse IN (0,1) THEN HR.HireID END) / 
          NULLIF(COUNT(HR.HireID), 0)
       , 0) AS percentage
from
    NewHire NH
    LEFT JOIN
    Hire_Response HR ON NH.HireID = HR.HireID
group by
    NH.HireID
```

Note you need to include HireID in the output. There is no guaranteed order to a result set unless ORDER BY is used, so you can't assume your list of percentages will be in order

Comment: But is there a way to also incorporate my stored procedure, since it returns the NewHire table in a specific way, then I need to get the percentages from that table from top to bottom?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332509/call-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-cte/6332549#6332549 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439005/set-var-exec-storedprocedure/5441380#5441380 for how to capture stored prcoedure output. Then use this temp table not NewHire. If you really want to

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create a temp table with the columns the stored proc will return. Then you insert the data into it by executing the stored proc as part of the insert. Then you insert into your table using a select stament instead of a values statment.

Alternatively you could create a table-valued function isnted of the stored proc and do only the one step of an insert with a select statment that cals the table-valued function.