# Using EXEC command as INSERT VALUE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

I want to be able to do something like this:
My stored proc will always return a number (tinyint)

```
INSERT INTO CustomerSelections
           ([draw_date]
           ,[val1]
           ,[val2]
           ,[val3]
           ,[val4]
           ,[val5]
           ,[val6])
     VALUES
           (
           '2013-07-05'
           ,EXEC GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
           ,EXEC GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
           ,EXEC GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
           ,EXEC GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
           ,EXEC GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
           ,EXEC GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
           )
```

But i am not aware of how to get the values in there?

**UPDATE:**
I tried something like this:

I put the passed values into a stored proc called:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUniqueLottoNumber] 

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GenerateRandomNumbers]
        @StartNumber = 1,
        @EndNumber = 49,
        @QuantityToOutput = 1,
        @AllowDuplicates = 0

END
```

Then did this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Number TINYINT)
DECLARE @q nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @return_value int
SET @q = 'EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[GetUniqueLottoNumber]';

INSERT INTO  #tmp (Number)
EXEC sp_executesql @q
```

But it doesnt like it when i put @q in the insert values.

Comment: GenerateRandomNumbers should be a function and not a stored procedure. Then this question will almost solve itself. Problem is that you have not shown the code for your stored procedure, so we are unable to rewrite your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you need to call the procedure 6 times? Why can't call the SP with a parameter of how many responses do you want?

anyway try something like this.

```
DECLARE @val1 INT
DECLARE @val2 INT
DECLARE @val3 INT 
DECLARE @val4 INT 
DECLARE @val5 INT 
DECLARE @val6 INT 

EXEC @val1 = GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
EXEC @val2 = GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
EXEC @val3 = GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
EXEC @val4 = GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
EXEC @val5 = GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
EXEC @val6 = GenerateRandomNumbers 1, 49, 1, 0
INSERT INTO CustomerSelections
           ([draw_date]
           ,[val1]
           ,[val2]
           ,[val3]
           ,[val4]
           ,[val5]
           ,[val6])
     VALUES
           (
           '2013-07-05'
           ,@val1
           ,@val2
           ,@val3
           ,@val4
           ,@val5
           ,@val6
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should declare some parameters, and than pass those variables to each exec statement then use that variables in the insert statatement. You can follow below link for details.

[Set return value of a stored procedure to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439005/set-var-exec-storedprocedure)